# Is this a valid cron expression for Quartz scheduler?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

Here is an example of the type of cron schedule that I am trying to express.

```
0 0 16 ? 2 7#3,1#4,2#4,3#4
```

So: '4:00:00 on the 3rd Saturday, 4th Sunday, 4th Monday, and 4th Tuesday of February.'

I am mostly concerned with the last part of the statement. I don't know whether or not I can set multiple x#y days and have it work. I tried running it throught [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/), and it said it was valid but did not return the expected schedule - it only read the first day of week that I set. Does anyone know if this will work, or know of an accurate way to validate if it does?

Comment: You can test the cron expression for quartz in this site: http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: @RafaelTeles I did as such, and it said that it was a valid expression but it did not show me the expected schedule.